# URL rewrites and pagination

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination

I must say that I am a complete nooby at Wordpress custom URL rewrites. I have searched for past many days to find a clear explanation of how to determine and write correct pattern for URL rewrites. I have a custom page template that uses query var passed to it, e.g. http://example.com/pagename?user=username. In this "pagename" refers to the custom page template and "user" refers to the custom query var. I need this to be represented using the URL http://example.com/pagename/username.

I also require the above to work with pagination. So http://example.com/pagename/username/page/2 should be able to represent http://example.com/pagename/page/2?user=username

It would be great if someone can provide me with a working example and an explanation of how I should determine and write correct pattern for URL rewrites.

Regards,
John

Comment: Will `pagename` be dynamic, or a 'known', static slug?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Thx for the reply. "pagename" shall be a known static slug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending @Stephen Harris' excellent answer, I would opt for;

```
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules' );
function my_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'mypageslug/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?pagename=mypageslug&user=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 2 ),
        'mypageslug/([^/]+)/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?pagename=mypageslug&user=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 )

    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

This follows the defacto regex standard used in WordPress core. The main change from Stephen's code sample is the use of `$wp_rewrite->index` to ensure the rewrite is passed through to WordPress (otherwise it may get added to the 'external'rewrite list).

Secondly, and most importantly, passing the `pagename` var in the query string - this means WordPress will behave as if it were ordinarily loading a page with the slug `mypageslug`.

**UPDATE:** I forgot to add, make sure `user` is a public query var, otherwise WordPress won't map it from the URL. Either filter it in with `query_vars` or add it using the global `$wp`;

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
function my_query_vars( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = 'user';
}

// my preferred method - make sure you run this only after 'init' has fired!
$GLOBALS['wp']->add_query_var( 'user' );

// then once the request has been parsed (anything after the action 'parse_request')
$user = get_query_var( 'user' );
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thx for the inputs!

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem and successfully solved it. In fact I recently wrote [this blog post](http://www.harriswebsolutions.co.uk/blog/2011/create-your-own-archive-page-with-wordpress/) which used this solution.

WordPress uses rules to make the URls pretty, the idea is to use a filter to call a function that add rules (then after going to settings > Permalinks and clicking save the rules should be added). This is the code:

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules');
function my_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $new_rules = array(
     'pagename/(.+)' => 'pagename?user='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
       );

  // Add the new rewrite rule into the top of the global rules array
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

The idea is that WordPress checks to see if the url is of the form www.example.com/pagename/something and uses that something to set the user variable.

To get pagination to work you'll need to add the following rule to the $new_rules array - **above** the rule already there (this is because WordPress checks the rules in order).

```
    'pagename/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})' => 'pagename?user='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&paged='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
```

Similarly this checks for www.example.com/pagename/something/page/2 say and interprets this as example.com/pagename?user=username&paged=2. (Paged is the query variable recognised by WordPress for determining the page in pagination).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx for the reply. I read through your blog post and found it informative. However, the solution you suggested displays the homepage instead of the custom page template. I have flushed the rewrite rules. Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Comment: @user9094 Check out my answer, which follows on from Stephen's.

Comment: @user9094 - what happens when you try http://example.com/pagename?user=username? The solution above simply re-writes the url, so if you go the above to work, then http://example.com/pagename/username should also work.

Comment: @StephenHarris example.com/pagename?user=username does work. I used TheDeadMedic's extended code and now it works absolutely perfect. Thx for your inputs!