# Custom Post Type/ Taxonomy URL rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have a custom post type registered: 'jobs'

```
// set up labels
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Jobs',
        'singular_name'      => 'Job',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New Job',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Job',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Job',
        'new_item'           => 'New Job',
        'all_items'          => 'All Jobs',
        'view_item'          => 'View Job',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Jobs',
        'not_found'          =>  'No Jobs Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Jobs found in Trash',
        'menu_name'          => 'Jobs',
    );

    //register post type
    register_post_type( 'jobs', array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'has_archive'         => 'jobs',
        'public'              => true,
        'supports'            => array( 
            'title', 
            'editor', 
            'excerpt', 
            'thumbnail',
            'page-attributes' 
        ),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'query_var'           => true,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-book-alt',
        'rewrite'             => array( 
            'slug'            => 'jobs/%job_status%',
            'with_front'      => false
        ),

        )

    );
```

And a custom Taxonomy: 'status'

```
$labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Status', 'taxonomy general name', 'trademanager' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Status', 'taxonomy singular name', 'trademanager' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Statuses', 'trademanager' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Statuses', 'trademanager' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Status', 'trademanager' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Status:', 'trademanager' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Status', 'trademanager' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Status', 'trademanager' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Status', 'trademanager' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Status Name', 'trademanager' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Status', 'trademanager' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'jobs/%job_status%', 'with_front' => false ),
    );
```

I would like the urls to be: jobs/** specific status (like category) **/post

I found this function:

```
function tm_jobs_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'jobs' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'status' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%job_status%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'tm_jobs_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

Which very nicely makes that url, however it just returns a 404 error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your post type and taxonomy have the same slug, your taxonomy slug shouldn’t contain the taxonomy query var, it should just be `jobs`

Comment: after every edit, you need to flush permalink before to try. it's what Solhan explains in his answer

Answer (score 1):

Open **Settings > Permalinks** and just click on the Save Settings button without any changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Solhan but that isn't the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Changed taxonomy rewrite to:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'jobs', 'with_front' => false ),
```

Changed post type rewrite to:

```
'rewrite' => true
```

Added the following functions:

```
function tm_jobs_generating_rule($wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'status',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    $post_type = 'jobs';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {    

        $rules['jobs/' . $term->slug . '/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type. '&jobs=$matches[1]&name=$matches[1]';

    }
    // merge with global rules
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'tm_jobs_generating_rule');

function tm_change_link( $permalink, $post ) {

    if( $post->post_type == 'jobs' ) {
        $resource_terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'status' );
        $term_slug = '';
        if( ! empty( $resource_terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $resource_terms as $term ) {
                // The featured resource will have another category which is the main one
                if( $term->slug == 'featured' ) {
                    continue;
                }
                $term_slug = $term->slug;
                break;
            }
        }
        $permalink = get_home_url() ."/jobs/" . $term_slug . '/' . $post->post_name;
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'tm_change_link',10,2);
```

All working correctly.